# Spring MVC Apache Server integration

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-mvc, web-applications

I have developed a Spring MVC app that can detect Ajax requests sent into my local environment 'localhost:8000/examplePath' with a json body being received as a mapped parameter. So, until here, all is fine. 
My question is: Do i still need to deploy my application on a container 'Apache Tomcat/ HTTP Server for example' for my application to be accessible externally on a possible production environment, and if so why?

I want to better understand the necessity of such, if my backend 'Spring MVC app' can already receive and respond to ajax requests

Comment: If you want your application to be accessible over the internet then it must be deployed on some sort of server which is available over the internet. Localhost is not available over the internet since that always points to your local machine.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment plus Ivan Lynch's answer kinda got it clicking to me. I was confusing the conceps of web application and web server. With your answers and a little google, i got a better concept of it, i believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring MVC creates a Web application that must be deployed to a Web Application Server to run. The server handles the low level stuff such as raw sockets and the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you can't access from internet to your local environment, you need a public adress to access your application from everywhere only if you want to access it over internet otherwise can do it with a local network connection to access it.

If you want any container, you can do it easy with [Pivotal](https://pivotal.io/). This a container platform for Spring apps.